# Replacing word in a string with another string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, str-replace

Does anyone know any regex expression where I can replace a word found in a string with another string?

```
var replacement = "car";
var toReplace = "boat";
var str = "banana boats or boat"
str = str.replace(toReplace, replacement);
```

I want str to be equals to "banana boats or car" instead of "banana cars or car"

Any suggestions?

Comment: `str` already equals `'banana boats or boat'`.

Comment: Is your isse that only the first occurrence gets replaced using `String-prototype.replace`?

Comment: `str.replace(new RegExp(toReplace, "g"), replacement) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a word boundary `\b` for replacing only the whole word, not parts of a word in a new created regular expression with the wanted word.

```js
var replacement = "car",
    toReplace = "boat",
    str = "banana boats or boat";
    
str = str.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + toReplace + '\\b', 'g'), replacement);

console.log(str);
```

Comment: if you like to replace more than one word, you could add a global flag `'g'` as second parameter of the regex cosntructor.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `global` flag for multiple matches. So pass this as the replacement regex:

```
new RegExp(toReplace, "g")
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the **first** instance of the search string `toReplace` in `str`.

To replace **all** instances of `toReplace` in `str`, use a [`RegEx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) object and the `g` (global) flag with `toReplace` as the search string:

```js
var replacement = "car";
var toReplace = "boat";
var str = "banana boats or boat";

var toReplaceRegex = new RegExp(toReplace, "g");
str = str.replace(toReplaceRegex, replacement); 
console.log(str); // prints "banana cars or car"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear because **str** already equals "banana boats or boat" by default before you changed it! 
...but you can do this if you insist

```
var replacement = "car"; 
var toReplace = "boat"; 
var str = "banana boats or boat" 
str = str.replace(replacement, toReplace);
```